# get a hash of params with form_tag

Tags: arrays, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have been looking around for an answer to my problem, without any success so far...

I would like to group some params in hashes after submitting a form, I would like it to look like:

**"mysurvey"=>{ 
{"my question1"=>["my first answer", "my second answer","my third answer"]},
{"my question2"=>["my other first answer", "my other second answer","my other third answer"]}
}**

```
<%= form_tag (@survey) do |f| %>

      my first question: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
      answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
      answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
      answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>

      my second question: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
      answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
      answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
      answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][]" %>
<%= submit_tag "envoyer" %>
```

**considering mysurvey is the unique attribute of the survey model.**

I cannot find a way for grouping each question for their respective answers, is it possible?
If you have any ideas or to solve this problem, let me know!
thank you very much!
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to take some time to read this section of the form guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions

It's hard to know from your question the right answer without knowing more about the Model as well but I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
  my first question: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question1]" %>
  answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question1][]" %>
  answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question1][]" %>
  answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question1][]" %>

  my second question: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question2]" %>
  answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question2][]" %>
  answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question2][]" %>
  answer: <%= text_field_tag "survey[mysurvey][question2][]" %>
```

However the question element `survey[mysurvey][question1]` in each answer above depends on how your Model is structured; the rest will give you the data format you are looking for.

A nicer way to possibly loop over your Model is this:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |survey_form| %>
  <%= survey_form.text_field :question %>
  <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= survey_form.fields_for question, index: question do |question_form|%>
      <%= question_form.text_field :answer %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks Bryan! this is exactly what I was looking for, it works great to pass the hash in the form, but now I've got a problem with the strong parameters: Neither #params.require(:survey).permit(mysurvey:[][]) or params.require(:survey).permit(mysurvey:[]) works...wrong number or arguments...how would you fix this problem? thanks!

Comment: you want to address them like this: (:mysurvey => []) take a look at the README here: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters